# Starting with scroll at bottom ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll, react-component

I have 2 components (parent and child). The child component has a long list of messages from from server in a scrollable div. I simply want to start the page with the scroll at the bottom - like a normal chat. I don’t want to see it scroll to the bottom. Can I do this with javascript or CSS?

Here's an example of what I want. Note: **Not using FlatLists**.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-h32if?file=/src/App.js

Thanks in advance.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component{

    render(){
      return(
  
        <div>
                <ChildComponent key={uniqueKey()} stream_uid={this.props.match.params.stream_uid} />       
        </div>
      )
    }
  
}


class ChildComponent extends Component{

    constructor() {

        this.state = {
          chat_messages: []
        }

    }

    componentDidMount () {

        this.props.dispatch(getStream(this.props.stream_uid,1,this.props.history)); 

        if(this.props.stream) {

            this.setState({
                chat_messages: this.props.stream.stream.messages
            })
        }

    }

  render(){

    return(
        <div>

            {Array.isArray(this.state.chat_messages) && this.state.chat_messages.map(message => {                           
                return (
                    <div>
                        <div>{message.username}</div>
                        <div>{message.text}</div>
                    </div>
                )

            })}                                                            
        </div>

    )

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by setting the div to scroll to bottom like this

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const listRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    listRef.current.scrollTo(0, listRef.current.scrollHeight, "auto");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      style={{ height: "200px", overflowY: "scroll" }}
      id="list"
      ref={listRef}
    >
      <div>Mesages</div>
      <div>Mesages</div>
      <div>Mesages</div>
      <div>Mesages</div>
      <div>Mesages</div>
      <div>Mesages</div>
      <div>Mesages</div>
      <div>Mesages</div>
      <div>Mesages</div>
      <div>Mesages</div>
      <div>Mesages</div>
      <div>Mesages</div>
      <div>Mesages</div>
      <div>Mesages</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

this is a codesndbox [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-khayyam-eu10z?file=/src/App.js:0-721)

Answer (score 0):

I created a parent view to react.
Here is a demo look it

[https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-forked-2o3dq?file=/src/App.js][1]

```
<View style={styles.main}>
        <FlatList
          ref={(ref) => (this._flatlistRef = ref)}
          inverted
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} // does not work
          contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          onEndReached={this.props.onLoadMore}
        />
      </View>
 container: {
    overflowY: "scroll",
    height: 200,
    backgroundColor: "red"
  },
```